# Counting with condition in summarize and group_by in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have following df

| item | cash |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1000 |
| B | 2800 |
| A | 2000 |
| B | 1500 |
| A | 3000 |
| A | 4000 |

My desired output is,

| item | count1 | count2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 0 |

What I have tried so far is,

```
df_summary <- df %>%
    group_by(item) %>%
    summarise(count1 = sum(cash > 2000),
              count2 = sum(cash <= 1000))
```

But it gives NA for the count1 and count2 columns. I checked cash column in numeric. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Perhaps some `NA`s? You could try `sum(cash > 2000, na.rm = TRUE)`.

Comment: Yes, it worked. I just forgot about the NA values in the column. thanks.